# How to read logs from txt file using apache flume

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a problem reading continuously growing .txt file using flume. I know that I can read something from net using for instance

```
a1.sources.r1.type = netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 44444
```

but how to do it with text file? What should I pass instead of netcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved that. It was necessary to provide following lines in the 'config' file:

```
a1.sources.r1.type = exec
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -F /path/to/file/
a1.sources.r1.channels = channel
```

instead of previous ones and then call flume-ng with this config file.